# How to track a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I am new to this site.  While browsing questions, I've found some to be very interesting.  Can anyone tell me how to track those questions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to mark a question as a favorite? Find other interesting questions? If the latter, how do you define interesting?

Comment: Mark the little star, then it will be in you favourites within your profile

Comment: he's asking how you can get notified of changes in that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark them favorite by click star below the vote then you will get notifications of any updates on that post in you profile favorites section.

> [image]